# how to keep format when converting time to text

Tags: excel

I have a column of time values that looks like this:

```
Time 
1:33
1:34
1:35
```

I want to convert this to text (or general) format that look like this:

```
Time 
1:33
1:34
1:35
```

Here is what I have tried:

- Copy and paste as value
- Change format to "General"
- Change format to "Text"

They all come out looking like this:

```
Time
0.06458
0.06666
0.06875
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a formula to do this.

```
=Text(A1,"h:mm")
```

should do the trick. That will make the result dynamic, i.e. if the time in cell A1 changes, the result of the formula will change, too.

You can also copy the results and use Paste Special > Values to get a list of editable text values.